# Install Firebug Extension Manually

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug, firebug-lite, firebug1.5

I want to install Firebug manually and update configuration settings on my own. I followed below steps:

1. Downloaded `firebug-2.0b1.xpi`  file (3 MB)
2. Extracted the content by using winRAR.
3. put this extracted folder "firebug-2.0b1" inside "`C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\extensions`"

Now, I run Firefox, but It seems firebug is not installed. This doens't work because some configurations are not done or Profile is not updated. I could like to know if any changes I need to do in folder.

I am doing this because, I couldn't install by drag & drop .xpi file on firefox or install through browser itself.

Comment: Which configuration settings are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

To install Firebug manually you have to do it differently. There are two ways to run extensions manually:

**1. Extract the XPI**

1. Download the XPI file that contains the extension
2. Locate the 'extensions' folder within your profile (e.g. via Firefox menu > *Help* > *Troubleshooting Information* > *Show Folder*)
3. Create a new folder within the 'extensions' folder and call it like the add-on's id (for Firebug this is `firebug@software.joehewitt.com`)
4. Extract the XPI into that folder

**2. Get the sources from the git repository**

A detailed description for how to do that can be found on the [development setup description on the Firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Internals#Development_Setup). It's similar to the description above with the addition that you'll be able to always get the latest sources.

Answer (score 1):

Two notes:

1. The folder name must be the same as the addon's ID (look in install.rdf of the addon) In your case it's not **firebug-2.0b1** , but **firebug@software.joehewitt.com**
2. The directory where the addon should be placed is not where the
   Firefox itself is installed, but into your Firefox's profile. By default it's in **%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*XXXXX*\extensions\** (where ***XXXXX*** is name of your profile folder. More info about profiles you can find [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox))

Comment: +1 Wow.. Its too valuable information ! I am trying this tomo