# Can the time the found row in Firebug is highlighted be changed?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I use Firebug's search feature.

The row with search result is highlighted but only briefly.
Is there a way to keep the highlight until I click inside code window? Or for some predefined time (for example, 30 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time the row containing the match is highlighted can't be influenced at the moment and is set to [1.3 seconds](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/34f747662f1a512e18e1e7ea4d52a9a90abddfd3/extension/content/firebug/lib/css.js#L589). Though the match itself will keep being selected.

You may want to [make an enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry?template=User%20enhancement%20request), though, to add a preference for the timing of the highlighting.

Comment: Can I build version of Firebug with changed `timeout` value (using Github sources)?

Comment: Sure, just have a look at [my answer I posted yesterday to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23107461/install-firebug-extension-manually/23110216#23110216) for how to do that.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to use your instruction.